# `using` inside a namespace in C++ module is not limited to the namespace

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

Given the following module `example`

```cpp
module;

#include "example.h" // `namespace cxx { struct example {}; }`

export module example;

export namespace cxx::containers
{
    using cxx::example;
}
```

`cxx::containers::example` becomes accessible from `cxx::example` as well where I only expected `cxx::containers::example` to appear.

```cpp
import example;

int main()
{
    auto v1 = cxx::containers::example();
    auto v2 = cxx::example();
}
```

What is the reason that `cxx::example` is visible even though I am only using it inside the namespace `cxx::containers::example` and that `#include` directives in the global `module;` fragment should be localized to their module?

Comment: Creating the namespace `containers` in the namespace `std` is undefined behaviour. Does this also happen if you rename `std::containers` into something not in `std::`? Also, this doesn't seem to find `std::vector` with clang++ 14 or g++ 11

Comment: @Artyer this appears to be only happening with `std::` and I am using latest MSVC.

Comment: I could reproduce it on msvc without the undefined behaviour by renaming `std` -> `x` and including a different file which contains `namespace x { struct vector { vector(...) {} }; }`, so this seems to be a difference between gcc/clang and msvc

Comment: @Artyer interesting, yeah just confirmed same behavior too, seems like a compiler bug maybe?

Comment: @YSC I have edited the question to with full reproduction without `std`

Comment: Probably because of [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/module.import#7.sentence-2). :)

Comment: @Life4gal I'll admit i can't fully understand it but it appears to be applying to actual import/export of modules, while the code in my question makes use of regular includes in the global module fragment, which as far as I know should _not_ be transited to importers of the module, there's also the fact that clang doesn't seem to have this issue. I wonder what gcc does..

Comment: @RickySpanish: What's even weirder about this is that if you `export using X::Y` in a namespace `Z` that *isn't* nested within `X`... it works. That is, you can't access `X::Y`; you can only access `Z::Y`. This oddity makes me think it's a compiler bug, but I can't really understand how using directives work with `export`, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @NicolBolas: There aren’t any *using-directive*s here, just *using-declaration*s.

Comment: @NicolBolas any questions on my answer?

Comment: @NicolasBolas (Using Visual Studio 17.7.2) I am seeing that `auto v2 = X::Y();`, compiles with 0 errors with test case `export using X::Y;` in stand-alone `namespace Z`. I.e. Whether Z is nested in the same namespace that Y is in, has no bearing on this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The strict answer ("the reason that `cxx::example` is visible") is that it's an **MSVC bug**: the declaration of `cxx::example` isn't exported, so it isn't found by name lookup outside the module in question ([basic.lookup.general]/2.3, except in certain circumstances involving dependent ADL ([basic.lookup.argdep]/4)).

Since C++20 was published, the wording for *using-declaration*s has been significantly revised to clarify the relationship between the original and new declaration.  A *using-declaration* is not a **redeclaration** of the original entity or typedef (which is why it can be separately exported); instead, name lookup **replaces** a *using-declarator* with the declarations to which it refers ([basic.lookup.general]/3).  The *using-declaration* for `cxx::containers::example` **precedes** `main` because it is exported (/2.3); the declaration of `cxx::example` itself does not, so it isn't found ([basic.lookup.qual.general]/3, [class.member.lookup]/1, and a different part of [basic.lookup.general]/3) except via the aforementioned replacement.

The wording for the only distantly related ***using-directive*** has also changed (as a retroactive Defect Report) to generally allow and give meaning to exported *using-directive*s ([basic.lookup.unqual]/1, [namespace.qual]/1, [module.interface]/4).  (They could already be exported in header units.)  Of course, if you **don’t** export them you can use them just for convenience within a module without affecting your clients!

Comment: Excellent, can you please add a little bit of clarification for the last paragraph? What is a `distantly related using-directive`. And what do you mean by `They could already be exported in header units. It remains a valuable feature that you can use them just for convenience within a module without exporting them and thereby affecting your clients!`

Comment: @RickySpanish: I mean that both use `using` but are quite different in mechanism; you didn’t ask about `using namespace`, but it seemed likely that people would want to see the corresponding information for it too, especially since it was initially impossible to export them except implicitly by putting them in a header unit.  The last bit is really an endorsement of non-exported *using-directive*s, which have the convenience that has tempted so many without the worst of the side effects.

Comment: Is it an MSVC bug? In the example, the namespace 'cxx::containers' is exported, so the entities in the namespace are generally exported. (Also, isn't namespace 'cxx' exported by the statement 'export namespace cxx::containers' ? Can namespace 'containers' within namespace 'cxx' be known externally without also externally knowing about its parent namespace 'cxx'?) Could you provide link to specification? Thank You

Comment: @Coder: Exporting a *namespace-definition* exports everything in (_that_ portion of) the namespace, but what is in that namespace is the *using-declaration* and not the declaration of `cxx::example` itself.  The namespace `cxx` is itself exported, but that doesn’t extend to its contents (in general).  I’ve provided lots of citations, but [module.interface]/2 is the one for the limited effect of `export namespace`.

Comment: @Coder: I’m already citing the standard—what further authoritative source are you hoping for?

Comment: @DavisHerring as mentioned, a link to the section of the spec. would be handy but also is this documentation inaccurate? learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/… Approximately halfway down the page - Quote: "If you put export in front of a namespace, for example export namespace N { ... }, everything defined within the braces is exported." Note that is states that "everything" is exported. Could the MSVC implementation be purposeful based on an interpretation of the spec.?

Comment: @Coder: Of course the *using-declaration* is exported.  The question isn’t about that, though: it’s about the **name** `cxx::example`, which is not exported even though a *using-declaration* referring to it is.  Nor is `cxx` itself being exported enough its contents not declared inside `export namespace {…}`.

Comment: @DavisHerring, I upvoted your answer. I see the logic of your statement that the namespace cxx is itself exported, but generally not its content. Thank You. (Interesting also that ReSharper C++ flags the error, but the compiler doesn't!)

Answer (score 1):

The [current state of module support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20) on compilers is not well.
So the short answer is:
**Expect Bugs and Oddities**

The best supported compiler is MSVC (_MSC_VER >= 1929). Both clang and gcc are partiality supported.

Clang recently cleaned up and improved their standard compliance in this [fix for the bug](https://reviews.llvm.org/D122119).

It would appear the code in the question demonstrates behavior that matches the standard. Specifically the [visibility rules for imported names](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.scope.namespace) (emphasis mine):

> Entities declared in a namespace-body are said to be members of the namespace, and names introduced by these declarations into the declarative region of the namespace are said to be member names of the namespace.
> A namespace member name has namespace scope.
> Its potential scope includes its namespace from the name's point of declaration on-wards; and for each *using-directive that nominates the member's namespace, the member's potential scope includes that portion of the potential scope of the using-directive that follows the member's point of declaration*.

T believe the intent is that `using` would also export the part used.

I created a similar set of files for clang++ (1400.0.29.202) below that I used to test this.
example.ixx:

```
export module example;    
export namespace cxx {
    struct example {
        double pi;
    };
}
export namespace cxx::containers {
    using cxx::example;
}
```

example.cpp:

```
import example;
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    auto v1 = cxx::containers::example();
    auto v2 = cxx::example();
    v1.pi = v2.pi = 3.14;
    std::cout << v1.pi << std::endl << v2.pi << std::endl;
}
```

Compile:

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts --precompile -x c++-module example.ixx -o M.pcm
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -fmodule-file=M.pcm example.cpp -o test
./test
```

Comment: Interesting, but it seems that your explanation covers module's imports and exports while my question was more regarding the fact that I am using the global module fragment and normal `#include`, which should be local to the module since `example.h` isn't a module itself and doesn't export anything. In other words, `export namespace cxx` doesn't exist in my code, and `example.h` is in the global module fragment, so the only thing being exported and should be visible here is `cxx::containers` namespace and its contents.

 
Unless the bug you mentioned also covers all of that?

Comment: @RickySpanish Yes, this was an answer for the bounty, so it did deviate from your question slightly. One of the examples in the bug fix covered parts of your question here: https://reviews.llvm.org/differential/changeset/?ref=3255697 . The bug fix itself covers several implementation details to get it to follow the standard. Specifically handling for: **export module M;** and **export namespace {};** (anonymous). Also **export namespace N {};** and **export using namespace N;**.

Comment: @RickySpanish I just updated, to make it a bit more clear how this (I believe) answers both your question and NicolBolas's.

Comment: @JamesRisner: None of what you cited deals with the interaction of exporting with all of this. Do the visibility rules interact with exporting rules? If so, where is this spelled out?